# How to groupby list in c# and show result without foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, group-by

I am using .net core 5 web api project. I have following classes:

```
public class GroupedShowbackSummaryListDto
{
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public List<GroupedProjectForShowbackSummary> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedProjectForShowbackSummary
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I would like group by rule id and show list of projects as response, I am trying:

```
 var queryable = _context.ShowbackSummaries.Where(x => x.ProjectId != null).AsQueryable();
  
 var summary = queryable.ToList();

 var grouped = summary.GroupBy(x => x.ShowbackRuleId).Select(c => new GroupedShowbackSummaryListDto
 {
            RuleId = c.Key,
            RuleName = c.Select(f => f.ShowbackRule.Name).First(),
            TotalPrice = c.Select(f => f.Price).Sum(),
            Projects = new List<GroupedProjectForShowbackSummary>
            {
                new()
                {
                    Id = c.Select(f => f.ProjectId).First(),
                    Name = c.Select(f => f.Project.Name).First(),
                    TotalPrice = c.Select(f => f.Price).First()
                }
            }
 }).ToList();


return grouped;
```

I know I am using first and it returns only first project but I would like to return all, if I switch to list int id for ex, it will show me:

```
[
 100,
 101,
...
]
```

I would like multiple result for my current response:

```
[
  {
    "ruleId": 1,
    "ruleName": "rule-1",
    "totalPrice": 400,
    "projects": [
      {
        "id": 1169,
        "name": "lubos-cncf",
        "totalPrice": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ruleId": 2,
    "ruleName": "rule-2",
    "totalPrice": 300,
    "projects": [
      {
        "id": 1169,
        "name": "lubos-cncf",
        "totalPrice": 300
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

P.S. Get all projects like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (inside your GroupBy-Expression):

```
                Projects = c.Select(f => 
                new GroupedProjectForShowbackSummary()
                {
                    Id = f.ProjectId,
                    Name = f.Project.Name,
                    TotalPrice = f.Price
                }).ToList()
```